# Small garden: Fully paved, Partial paved with grass or Full grass?

Tags: grass, containers, raised-beds, mowing, pavers

**What is the value in a maintaining a little grass patch in a small garden?**

We're moving from a a rural area with a big garden to an town where every house we can afford has a small garden. The reason we're moving is mainly due to due to the need to align commuting with schooling

I'm beginning to get used to the prices in the town (the rural location is cheap as it's a long commute, we're paying 2-3 times in the town for a house the same size with a much smaller garden)

What I'm wondering about though is the garden. We've seen a few houses with a fully paved garden and at first it feels odd as a garden should have grass. But then we've seen other gardens with a little patch of grass, and I'm just wondering; what is the point in grass in a small garden? I'd rather not have to mow a little patch of grass every week; but then I'm wondering if I really can live with a paved garden?

For context on our current garden; it's mainly fruit trees, fruit bushes, a couple of sheds and. We use the grass for walking on, lying on and children roll on it. I used to have ducks but they ruined the grass so no longer have them; we wouldn't be allowed ducks in the town anyway.

Comment: Best I can see that's down to your opinion, not a question with an answer that's right other than that. A small patch of grass is easily mown - depending how small you're talking, some can be clipped with shears, and none that I'd consider small should need anything more complex than a reel mower, which would still be quick and low-fuss  if used regularly and stored dry. Given a limited garden space I'd be more prone to planting things I can eat than grass, but that's me, not you. Fully paved is not to my taste at all, and ends up being a war on the weeds that want to grow anywway.

Comment: No one says your patch of grass has to be lawn grass. By context and language I assume you're in the UK, so it may not be possible to get some of these, but Carex pensylvanica is an excellent spreading no-mow sedge that'll give you that patch of green in the yard. You could also go with a groundcover: Mazus reptans (very low-growing and blooms sky-blue in May in the northern US), buffalo grass (a taller no-mow grass that may not be walkable due to height), or even just white clover.

Comment: In the "foolish things people spend money on to avoid a small amount of work" line, there are robot mowers, though surprisingly there don't seem to many "direct solar power" versions.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? And when you say 'small garden', how small? A photo or two of the area would be useful too